# Debugging a release build: still not hitting breakpoints - do I have to locate all of the PDBs? What if I can't?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 VC++. I am trying to debug a release build. I have it in release mode, and made all of the changes noted in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz(v=vs.100).aspx

As well as rebuilt the solution. The breakpoints are still complaining that the symbols have not been loaded.

When I try to debug, I have looked at the modules window and tried to hand-locate the PDBs. However, I have over 100 DLLs, half of which say "Cannot find or open the PDB file."

Do I need to manually go through and search for all of these PDB files? I started, but I checked out the code from a company repository and all of the PDBs are all over the place, it's a little bit of a mess. Also, if I can find the PDB file, sometimes the dates don't match up with the DLLs, and Visual Studio doesn't take them. I thought the PDB files were created when the project was built, so I thought they would be created again when I re-built the project, but maybe I am incorrect?

Is there any way around this problem, and is finding the PDBs the correct solution to being able to hit the breakpoints?

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you have the correct `.pdb` files for a release build the debugger might still not be able to set a breakpoint on a particular line (or it may get somewhat confused).  The optimizations performed in a release build can make it so there is no longer a good correspondence between the op-codes in the binary and the source lines.  If you don't even have the correct `.pbd` files, then the problem is worse. I'm not sure if you can convince the VS debugger to load a PDB if the checksum, timestamp or whatever is used to validate the symbols doesn't match.